# C#: Избавиться от повторяющегося кода

Tags: c#, if

У меня есть множественные проверки в if-е, они содержат в себе повторяющийся код, можно ли этого избежать? В дальнейшем символов для проверки будет больше.

[image]

Comment: Собери в хэшсет и проверяй на contains

Comment: Смотря, что Вы хотите добиться. Если Вы хотите исключить, что в Вашем коде есть спец символы - то Regex Вам  в помощь

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Делается это так. Добавляем нужные символы в `HashSet<char>` (кстати, в него нельзя добавить одинаковые символы ни случайно, ни специально). Далее везде в коде проверяешь есть ли символ в `HashSet<char>`.  Почитай про [`HashSet<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1), работает быстрее, чем обход массива, к примеру, на каждой итерации.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var charSet = new HashSet<char>(new[]
            {
                ' ', '-', ',', '.', '_', ':', ';', '?', '(', ')', '!'
            });

            string text = "Hi! My name is John.";
            Console.WriteLine(text);

            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                if (charSet.Contains(text[i]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Я бы сделал это при помощи [String.Contains()](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2) из-за наглядности

```
var map = " ,._:;&()!";
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) {
    if (map.Contains(text[i])) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Если же Вам важна производительность, все это дело можно сложить в [HashSet](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) и искать в нем

```
var map = " ,._:;&()!";
var set = new HashSet<char>(map);
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++) {
    if (set.Contains(text[i])) {
        ...
    }
}
```